# How to rewrite C goto and switch with idiomatically Rust Equivalents in bzip2 decompress function?

Tags: rust

I'm transitioning from C to Rust and am looking for the idiomatic way to rewrite a C code pattern involving goto with a switch case in Rust. Here's an example of my C code:

The C code is extraction of *.i code from bzip2

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int state = 15;
    int dummy = 0;
    switch (state) {
        case 15:
            dummy = 15; // set dummy to 15 under certain condition
            if (dummy == 15) goto endhdr_2;
            /* fallthrough */

        case 16:
            dummy = 16;
            printf("dummy");
            /* fallthrough */

        endhdr_2:
        case 42:
            dummy = 42;
            printf("dummy: %d", 42);
            /* fallthrough */

        case 43:
            dummy = 43;
            printf("dummy: %d", 43);
            /* fallthrough */
        
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that `goto` is not available in Rust, and Rust's match is somewhat different from C's switch. How can I best translate this pattern to Rust while adhering to Rust's idiomatic practices and ensuring the same functionality?

### Add additional Context to above code

The example of my C code above, which is an extraction from the code repo from [classic C program bzip2](https://gitlab.com/SheldonHH/bzip2), the `goto` logic specifically from the [`BZ2_decompress` function in decompress.c](https://gitlab.com/bzip2/bzip2/-/blob/master/decompress.c?ref_type=heads#L224).

I have attached the preprocess `.i` readability from the [decompress.i](https://gitlab.com/SheldonHH/bzip2/-/blob/master/decompress.i?ref_type=heads#L3085) file in here.

[Location that use goto](https://gitlab.com/SheldonHH/bzip2/-/blob/master/decompress.i?ref_type=heads#L3083-3085) in `decompress.i`

```c
case 14: s->state = 14; while (((Bool)1)) { if (s->bsLive >= 8) { UInt32 v; v = (s->bsBuff >> (s->bsLive-8)) & ((1 << 8)-1); s->bsLive -= 8; uc = v; break; } if (s->strm->avail_in == 0) { retVal = 0; goto save_state_and_return; };; s->bsBuff = (s->bsBuff << 8) | ((UInt32) (*((UChar*)(s->strm->next_in)))); s->bsLive += 8; s->strm->next_in++; s->strm->avail_in--; s->strm->total_in_lo32++; if (s->strm->total_in_lo32 == 0) s->strm->total_in_hi32++; };

if (uc == 0x17) goto endhdr_2;
```

and the [code after `endhdr_2:`](https://gitlab.com/SheldonHH/bzip2/-/blob/master/decompress.i?ref_type=heads#L3453-3464) in `decompress.i`

```c
      endhdr_2:

      case 42: s->state = 42; while (((Bool)1)) { if (s->bsLive >= 8) { UInt32 v; v = (s->bsBuff >> (s->bsLive-8)) & ((1 << 8)-1); s->bsLive -= 8; uc = v; break; } if (s->strm->avail_in == 0) { retVal = 0; goto save_state_and_return; };; s->bsBuff = (s->bsBuff << 8) | ((UInt32) (*((UChar*)(s->strm->next_in)))); s->bsLive += 8; s->strm->next_in++; s->strm->avail_in--; s->strm->total_in_lo32++; if (s->strm->total_in_lo32 == 0) s->strm->total_in_hi32++; };
      if (uc != 0x72) { retVal = (-4); goto save_state_and_return; };;
      case 43: s->state = 43; while (((Bool)1)) { if (s->bsLive >= 8) { UInt32 v; v = (s->bsBuff >> (s->bsLive-8)) & ((1 << 8)-1); s->bsLive -= 8; uc = v; break; } if (s->strm->avail_in == 0) { retVal = 0; goto save_state_and_return; };; s->bsBuff = (s->bsBuff << 8) | ((UInt32) (*((UChar*)(s->strm->next_in)))); s->bsLive += 8; s->strm->next_in++; s->strm->avail_in--; s->strm->total_in_lo32++; if (s->strm->total_in_lo32 == 0) s->strm->total_in_hi32++; };
      if (uc != 0x45) { retVal = (-4); goto save_state_and_return; };;
      case 44: s->state = 44; while (((Bool)1)) { if (s->bsLive >= 8) { UInt32 v; v = (s->bsBuff >> (s->bsLive-8)) & ((1 << 8)-1); s->bsLive -= 8; uc = v; break; } if (s->strm->avail_in == 0) { retVal = 0; goto save_state_and_return; };; s->bsBuff = (s->bsBuff << 8) | ((UInt32) (*((UChar*)(s->strm->next_in)))); s->bsLive += 8; s->strm->next_in++; s->strm->avail_in--; s->strm->total_in_lo32++; if (s->strm->total_in_lo32 == 0) s->strm->total_in_hi32++; };
      if (uc != 0x38) { retVal = (-4); goto save_state_and_return; };;
      case 45: s->state = 45; while (((Bool)1)) { if (s->bsLive >= 8) { UInt32 v; v = (s->bsBuff >> (s->bsLive-8)) & ((1 << 8)-1); s->bsLive -= 8; uc = v; break; } if (s->strm->avail_in == 0) { retVal = 0; goto save_state_and_return; };; s->bsBuff = (s->bsBuff << 8) | ((UInt32) (*((UChar*)(s->strm->next_in)))); s->bsLive += 8; s->strm->next_in++; s->strm->avail_in--; s->strm->total_in_lo32++; if (s->strm->total_in_lo32 == 0) s->strm->total_in_hi32++; };
      if (uc != 0x50) { retVal = (-4); goto save_state_and_return; };;
      case 46: s->state = 46; while (((Bool)1)) { if (s->bsLive >= 8) { UInt32 v; v = (s->bsBuff >> (s->bsLive-8)) & ((1 << 8)-1); s->bsLive -= 8; uc = v; break; } if (s->strm->avail_in == 0) { retVal = 0; goto save_state_and_return; };; s->bsBuff = (s->bsBuff << 8) | ((UInt32) (*((UChar*)(s->strm->next_in)))); s->bsLive += 8; s->strm->next_in++; s->strm->avail_in--; s->strm->total_in_lo32++; if (s->strm->total_in_lo32 == 0) s->strm->total_in_hi32++; };
      if (uc != 0x90) { retVal = (-4); goto save_state_and_return; };;
```

You can reproduce `decompress.i` by modifying [CMakeLists.txt](https://gitlab.com/SheldonHH/bzip2/-/blob/demo-build/CMakeLists.txt?ref_type=heads#L243) to add `add_definitions(-save-temps)`

You can cleanup the *.i using

```bash
for file in *.i; do awk '!/^#[ \t]*[0-9]+[ \t]+"/' "$file" > "${file}.tmp" && mv "${file}.tmp" "$file"; done
```

Comment: As C coder I would not allow this kind of code in a code base to begin with. It's hard to advice with such abstract code, my general advice will be don't do spaghetti code.

Comment: Without `goto` (which in this case I strongly discourage anyway) you can't translate this exactly as you normally would as you cannot break the instruction sequence as `goto` does. You must refactor your code.

Comment: Don't ask to translate; ask how to do what you want to do.

Comment: You're missing `break;` after all your `case` statements. I assume you want them on all of them!? As is, for output, I get `dummy: 42dummy: 43`

Comment: Assuming case 42 will end up changing `state`, this could easily be restructured to avoid the `goto` by surrounding the `switch` with an infinite loop, replacing the `goto endhdr_2;` with `state = 42; continue;` and have a `break;` at the end of the loop body.

Comment: @Craig Estey They oversimplified, yes. Fixed.

Comment: @ikegami I was thinking about moving the `case 15` above the `case 42` with `case 15: if (state != 15) break; /* fall through */ case 42:` But, with a loop, I think your solution would be cleaner. Particularly, since there probably _is_ such a loop in OP's _real_ code (based on the naming of `state`).

Comment: @ikegami given the OP's use of `goto` inside the `switch`, it is likely that they _intended_ the code to fall through between the `case`s and that the `break`s were deliberately omitted…

Comment: @Stargateur The C code is extraction of logic from [project bzip2 decompress.c](https://gitlab.com/bzip2/bzip2/-/blob/master/decompress.c?ref_type=heads#L106)

The function is `Int32 BZ2_decompress (DState* s)` which the `switch` includes nested `case`

I have saved the [decompress.i](https://gitlab.com/SheldonHH/bzip2/-/blob/master/decompress.i?ref_type=heads#L3085) preprocessed for readability.

Comment: @ikegami
 I have add some context to this situation in the original question, it's from [bzip2](https://gitlab.com/bzip2/bzip2/-/blob/master/decompress.c?ref_type=heads#L106)

Comment: FWIW there are pure Rust implementation of a Bzip2 [encoder](https://crates.io/crates/banzai) and [decoder](https://crates.io/crates/bzip2-rs). You might want to look at how they implement the equivalent function.

Comment: @ikegami my tasks is to translate bzip2 decompress function to rust, but the logic in C is quite complicated already, especially given so many nested `cases`

Comment: @Sheldon this code is from 1996 and I can guarantee you that bad code, unmaintainable, too long, declare variable in top of function, no bracket around if, spaghetti code. It's not because code "exist" it's good practice, like the good old saying 99% of C code should be buried 1 km underground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate both every `goto` and every fall from one case through to the next, we could restructure the code such that

```c
Int32 retVal = 0;
...
switch ( s->state ) {
   ...

   case ...:
      ...
      if ( ... )
         goto endhdr_2;  // Go to state 42.
      ...

   ...

   endhdr_2:
   case 42:
      s->state = 42;
      ...
      if ( ... ) {
         retVal = ...;
         // Exit the switch while skipping the assert.
         goto save_state_and_return;
      }
      ...
      // Go to state 43.

   case 43:
      s->state = 43;
      ...

   ...
}

...

save_state_and_return:
...
```

becomes

```c
Int32 retVal = 1;  // An illegal value for which we'll check for later.
...
while ( 1 ) {
   switch ( s->state ) {
      ...

      case ...:
         ...
         if ( ... ) {
            // Go to state 42.
            s->state = 42;
            continue;
         }
         ...

      ...

      case 42:
         ...
         if ( ... ) {
            retVal = ...;
            break;
         }

         ...

         // Go to state 43.
         s->state = 43;
         continue;

      case 43:
         ...

      ...
   }

   break;
}

if ( retVal == 1 ) {
   ...
   retVal = 0;
}

...
```

From what I just read about Rust, this should be easy to translate.

What follows is how we got to this.

---

**Eliminating `goto endhdr_2`**

Since the first thing which is done after the `goto` is to change the switch variable, we could restructure the code such that

```c
switch ( s->state ) {
   ...

   case ...:
      ...
      if ( ... )
         goto endhdr_2;  // Go to state 42.
      ...

   ...

   endhdr_2:
   case 42:
      s->state = 42;
      ...

   ...
}
```

becomes

```c
while ( 1 ) {
   switch ( s->state ) {
      ...

      case ...:
         ...
         if ( ... ) {
            // Go to state 42.
            s->state = 42;
            continue;
         }
         ...

      ...

      case 42:
         s->state = 42;
         ...

      ...
   }

   break;
}
```

---

**Eliminating fall-throughs**

From what I can tell, Rust doesn't support falling from one case through to the next, and the C code does does a lot of that. This same approach used to eliminate the `goto` could be used to emulate a fall through to another state.

```c
switch ( s->state ) {
   ...

   case 42:
      ...

      // Go to state 43.

   case 43:
      s->state = 43;
      ...

   ...
}
```

becomes

```c
while ( 1 ) {
   switch ( s->state ) {
      ...

      case 42:
         ...

         // Go to state 43.
         s->state = 43;
         continue;

      case 43:
         ...

      ...
   }

   break;
}
```

---

**Eliminating `goto save_state_and_return`**

There's a "million" instances of second `goto`: `goto save_state_and_return`. The point of that `goto` is to exit the switch. `goto` is used instead of `break` to skip an assert that follows the switch. So the `goto` can be replaced with a `break` as long as we also set some variable to indicate the assert should be skipped. We can take advantage of the fact that we always set `retVal` just before every `goto save_state_and_return` to avoid setting a new variable a "million" times. In other words, we could restructure the code so that

```c
Int32 retVal = 0;
...
switch ( s->state ) {
   ...

   case ...:
      ...
      if ( ... ) {
         retVal = ...;
         // Exit the switch while skipping the assert.
         goto save_state_and_return;
      }
      ...

   ...
}

...

save_state_and_return:
...
```

becomes

```c
Int32 retVal = 1;  // An illegal value for which we'll check for later.
...
switch ( s->state ) {
   ...

   case ...:
      ...
      if ( ... ) {
         retVal = ...;
         break;
      }
      ...

   ...
}

if ( retVal == 1 ) {
   ...
   retVal = 0;
}

...
```

Comment: Added to my answer